# Find the exact value of the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big\{\mathrm{e}-\big(1+\frac1n\big)^{n}\big\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How can we find the *exact* value of the infinite sum 
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{\mathrm{e}-\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^n\right\}?
$$

This problem appears in:

[T. Andreescu, T. Radulescu & V. Radulescu, *Problems in Real Analysis: Advanced Calculus on the real line*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Problems-Real-Analysis-Advanced-Calculus/dp/0387773789/ref=sr_1_14?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1394700711&sr=1-14&keywords=andreescu), p.114.

Comment: If I have interpreted your question correctly, the series diverges.

Comment: It should be noted we're actually looking for the summands to be "the fractional part of"

Comment: @Sabyasachi I agree.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28e+-+%281%2B1%2Fn%29%5En%29+from+1+to+infinity

Comment: It's a typo in the question. If you look in the book ([i found a pdf version online](http://faculty.mu.edu.sa/public/uploads/1331973962.6448Problems%20in%20Real%20Analysis%20Advanced%20Calculus%20on%20the%20Real%20Axis.pdf)) the question is clear. I can't edit the question, though.

Comment: I unupvoted it. I went on wolfram because something like this would be very much well known by wolfram because of the precise term *beautiful* I feel a little let down.

Comment: @Tyler: All members of the series are less than $1$.

Comment: At @Tyler my bad. I suggested a $\LaTeX$ edit. That is why you can't edit it now.

Comment: @Tyler edit approved. You *can* edit it now. Go ahead. Add a link to the book too.

Comment: And its page number

Comment: @Tyler weird. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+frac%28e+-+%281%2B1%2Fn%29%5En%29+from+1+to+infinity this diverges too?

Comment: As it is written, the taking of the fractional part is redundant:  $0 < e - (1+1/n)^n < 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Yep. It diverges too. This is very very weird indeed

Comment: @Sabyasachi That makes finding the exact value easy, though: $+\infty$.

Comment: Exactly friends the series diverges but why???

Comment: @DanielFischer I like your sass

Comment: @k1.M I guess because $(1+1/n)^n$ fails to converge to $e$ “quickly enough.”

Comment: Yes, did we consider the fact that the book *wanted* us to say $+\infty$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that "*By the comparison test, the series diverges*".

Comment: It still is an interesting question.

Comment: It diverges by comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @all OP has 39 rep. 7 upvotes on this question. No other question on his profile. It can only mean 8 upvotes and a downvote. 1 + 8*5 - 2. Why the downvote?

Comment: @sabyaschi if you click on the question's "score" you can actually see the number of up/downvotes :)

Comment: I think that seeing scores is either a rep privilege or I have a bug. Damn, back to sherlock deduction skills.

Comment: On a related note, $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(e-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\bigg)=1.$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Privilege, 1000 rep, if memory serves. Not too far away for you, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer no not too far. I got to 600 in a month. With +100 from the association bonus. so another 400 in a month should be ok. :p

Comment: @Lucian citation? Can I post a question about that? You could prove it( I assume you are familiar with it). Looks very interesting to me.

Comment: Nope. I was just inspired by the interesting question to find a similar series, and confirmed the result with *Mathematica*. :-)

Comment: Why "beautiful"?

Comment: All the more reason for posting that question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We have the following approximation for $\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^n$:
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}=\mathrm{e}^{n\log(1+\frac{1}{n})}=\mathrm{e}^{1-\frac{1}{2n}+{\mathcal O}(n^{-2})}=\mathrm{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+{\mathcal O}\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)\right),
$$
since
$$
\log \Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+{\mathcal O}\Big(\frac{1}{n^3}\Big)
\quad\text{and}\quad \mathrm{e}^h=1+h+{\mathcal O}(h^2),
$$
for $h$ small and $n$ large.
Hence
$$
\mathrm{e}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}=\frac{\mathrm{e}}{2n}+{\mathcal O}\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\!\Big).
$$
This implies that the series diverges, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{\mathrm{e}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}\right\}=\infty.
$$
**Note.** All the term of the sequence $$a_n=\mathrm{e}-\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\!\Big)^n, 
\quad n\in\mathbb N,$$ are positive, since $\mathrm{e}^{1/n}>1+\frac{1}{n}$. It is noteworthy that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big\{ \mathrm{e}-\big(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}\!\big)^n\big\}$, also of positive terms is convergent.

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning of converting the exponent operation into a multiplication operation on the top line?  Thanks.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis,Note that you must also prove that every element of the series is positive,i.e.,$$0<e-(1+\frac 1n)^n$$

Comment: @k1.M, it follows immediately from the equality $e - (1+1/n)^n = e/(2n) + O(1/n^2)$ that $e - (1+1/n)^n$ is positive for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, without using logs, note that if we expand $( 1+ \frac{1}{n})^{n}$ via the binomial theorem, for $2 \leq k \leq n,$ the $k$-th summand is $\frac{1}{k!}(1 - \frac{1}{n}) \ldots (1 - \frac{(k-1)}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{k!}(1 - \frac{1}{n}) .$ This means that 
$e - (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}.$ This is at least $\frac{1}{2n}$ for $n \geq 2.$ Hence the given sum is greater than or equal to $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n},$ which diverges.