# Software to draw Geometry in 2D, 3D

Tags: geometry, math-software

I am looking for a software to sketch moving figures as [this one](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/construct-triangleinscribe.html).
Thanks.

See also:

[image: math animation]

Comment: Your link is Flash.

Comment: Try [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/download/).

Comment: @Lucian I got a few quick [answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703288/prove-sum-n-1-inftye-sum-k-0n-frac1k-1/703320?noredirect=1#703320) to the proof of that factorial equation you posted.

Comment: Ask them?${}{}$

Comment: My question should be: how to do like that? Using software, algorithm, can I do by myself?

Comment: @LoveMath Yes you can do it. But first select a software. [GeoGebra is good.]

Answer (score 5):

That animation is custom-made in [Flash](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Professional), which is a perfect and full-blown tool to do 2D animations(and even games) like that but it has a quite heavy cost, even for the student license($\$19.99$ per month or $\$199$ per year).

- [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/download/) is a free tool
  for drawing geometry, and it has capabilities for doing interaction, animations, and it has a beta for 3D graphics. It is one of the best tools to do geometry, it has a quite limited online version and a full installed version (both free).
- Cut-the-knot [Geoboard](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Geoboard.shtml) is a fantastic applet(interactions, animations), and it has a very comfortable cost ($\$5$) for a license.
- To make architectural 3D graphics in a fast, simple way, I recommend the free version of [Sketchup](http://www.sketchup.com/es), that is also a fantastic tool to make desgins and it is also possible to do animations in 3D.
- As a full-blown 3D design tool I really recommend [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), a free program to do 3D in which you have total artistic capability, but because of that it does not have geometry-specific tools.

Answer (score 3):

**For 2D Geometry:**

There is http://www.robocompass.com/app - free and fantastic and does animate geometric constructions.

**For 3D Geometry:**

I have developed a free 3d drawing program that runs in modern browsers (html5). The English version is called [Geoservant 3D](https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/en/), the original German version is called [Geoknecht 3D](https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/de/).

There you can specify 3d shapes (solid geometry) and animate them by changing their values. See description on page how to change values: hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> and use the cursor keys. Also have a look at the [gallery](https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/en/#gallery) on the page to see what things you can achieve with this program using simple syntax. For each object the program calculates basic values (area, volume, vectors).

Example:

[image: 3d-coordinates of a cube with space diagonal and face diagonal]

For different colors you simply add the HEX color code in the end, e.g. `sphere(3|3|1 2){F00}`. If you add a value between 0 and 1 in brackets, you can define a transparency for each object, e.g. `sphere(3|3|1 2){F00}{0.75}`

Furthermore, variables can be defined. Example:

```
$x=4 
cuboid(4|-4|1 4 2 1)[0 $x $x]
vector(0|0|0 $x|$x|$x "$x")
```

A hemisphere can be created like that `sphere(0|0|4 4 0 6.28 1.55 3.14)`, see gallery on the site!

Languages: Geoservant is now available in German, English, Spanish, French, Russian, Swedish and Chinese - and accepts the objects specified in those languages, example: `长方体(4|1|1 2|4|1)`

#### Alternative

More complex and powerful: I find the 3D geometry tool [tinkercard.com](http://www.tinkercad.com) quite amazing.

Another program is the [Geodrafter 2D](https://www.matheretter.de/calc/geodrafter/) (English) or [Geozeichner 2D](https://www.matheretter.de/rechner/geozeichner/) (German) for two dimensional shapes.

Comment: Would you like to tell us how to change object colors? And how to make an hemisphere?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think interactive geometry software as referred can achieve what you are looking for.

Given your link example, what you are looking for is [Instrumenpoche](http://instrumenpoche.sesamath.net/). The tools is specifically developed by French mathematics teachers to demonstrate compas and ruler constructions.

It is free software but I am afraid you will need some basic French to navigate on its web site. You can try this [direct link to start](http://instrumenpoche.sesamath.net/v2/iep.php) to use the software, it is icons base, so the language should not be a barrier.

Once done, the construction can be replayed indefinitely, free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

I know a professor who raves about http://www.glowscript.org/