# Software for drawing 2D geometry with autosizes, coloring, etc

Tags: math-software

I'm searching for a software that will help me in solving geometric problems
I've found some similar questions like [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703428/software-to-draw-geometry-in-2d-3d) but they don't fit my expectations.

1. All basic shapes (circle, rectangle, triangle, custom polygons)
2. Snapping
3. Auto measure sizes
4. Ability to colorize each shape (optional)

I want such software to help myself in solving geometric (gamedev) problems

Comment: Your first linked post suggests Geogebra; what is wrong with that?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas i didn't find circle there. It has to ask for a formula but i don't want to bother with that

Comment: It is right there after the option for drawing a triangle. See [here](http://prntscr.com/v5zhob). All you need to do is specify three points through which a unique circle can be drawn