# Showing how this infinite sum diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left[\left( 1 + {1 \over n}\right)^{n} - {\rm e}\right]}$

I tried both root and ratio tests 
(for the root test, the expression became way too complex to handle)
but both didn't really work out.

Would there be an easy way of showing that this diverges?

Comment: see here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703207/find-the-value-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-mathrme-big1-frac1n-bign-rig

Comment: Essentially, you need to estimate $(1+1/n)^n-e$.

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't know there was already a question about it.

Comment: it popped up a couple of days ago and I was intrigued.  So when I saw yours I posted the link.  Hope it helps.